# Get element innerHTML and add to List

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick

I have a table and a list. I want the user to click on an item in the table and the text from the cell is added to the list.

```
function history_buff(obj){

    var elList = Document.getElementById("user_history");


    //alert("Trying to add item " + obj);
    var element = Document.getElementById(str(obj))
    var text = element.innerText || element.textContent;
    var user_item = element.innerHTML = text;

    alert("Trying to add: "  + user_item)


    var li = document.createElement("li");

    li.innerHTML = user_item.value;

    elList.appendChild(user_item);
}

function welcome(){
    alert("Welcome home!");
}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
    <div class="block" id="one">
        <table id="name_table">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Job</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="name_1">
                <td><a onclick="history_buff();" href="static\text_files\alex.txt">Alex</a></td>
                <td onclick="welcome();">12</td>
                <td>Analyst</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="name_2"> 
                <td><a href="static\text_files\bill.txt">Bill</a></td>
                <td>54</td>
                <td>Car Salesman</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="name_3">
                <td><a id="item_3" href="static\text_files\Rodrigo.txt">Rodrigo</a></td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td id="job_3" onclick="history_buff(this.id)">Merchant</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="block" id="two">
        <h2>History</h2>
        <ul id="user_history">
            <li>Nothing</li>
            <li>Something</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I've tried many different ways similar to this, but can't seem to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors in your function. Here is a fixed and working version:

```js
function history_buff(obj) {
  var elList = document.getElementById("user_history");
  //alert("Trying to add item " + obj);
  var element = document.getElementById(obj)
  var text = element.textContent;
  var user_item = text;

  alert("Trying to add: " + user_item);

  var li = document.createElement("li");

  li.innerHTML = user_item;

  elList.appendChild(li);
}

function welcome() {
  alert("Welcome home!");
}
```

```html
<div class="block" id="one">
  <table id="name_table">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Job</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name_1">
      <td><a href="static\text_files\alex.txt">Alex</a></td>
      <td onclick="welcome();">12</td>
      <td id="job_1" onclick="history_buff(this.id)">Analyst</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name_2">
      <td><a href="static\text_files\bill.txt">Bill</a></td>
      <td>54</td>
      <td id="job_2" onclick="history_buff(this.id)">Car Salesman</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name_3">
      <td><a id="item_3" href="static\text_files\Rodrigo.txt">Rodrigo</a></td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td id="job_3" onclick="history_buff(this.id)">Merchant</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="block" id="two">
  <h2>History</h2>
  <ul id="user_history">
    <li>Nothing</li>
    <li>Something</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is not the best way to do things, though.

Answer (score 1):

First, it is a bad habit to give your rows an ID, cause the records in the table could be dynamically generated, 
Secondly, one likely reason your code didn't run is that when defining the

`function history_buff(obj){
... do something
}`

but when calling the function, you didn't pass the obj as a parameter 
`ie <td><a onclick="history_buff();" href="static\text_files\alex.txt">Alex</a></td>`

finally,
` var element = Document.getElementById(str(obj)), 
why dont you try

var element = Document.getElementById(`${obj}`)` 
I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, I am hoping I can find a way to not use ID's as I was more adding them out of desperation to get it to work ;)

Answer (score 1):

- Embrace the function `addEventListener` to bind events.
- A string doesn't have a property called `value`, so, this `user_item.value` won't work.
- Append to the list the new element `li`.

This approach is preventing the default behavior of a link using the function `preventDefault` from the event object, this way you will be able to see the added elements to the parent element `user_history`.

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('td a'), function(a) {
  a.addEventListener('click', history_buff)
});

function history_buff(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var elList = document.getElementById("user_history");
  var text = this.innerText || element.textContent;
  var user_item = this.innerHTML = text;

  //console.log("Trying to add: " + user_item)

  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = user_item;

  elList.appendChild(li);
}

function welcome() {
  alert("Welcome home!");
}
```

```html
<div class="block" id="one">
  <table id="name_table">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Job</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name_1">
      <td><a href="static\text_files\alex.txt">Alex</a></td>
      <td onclick="welcome();">12</td>
      <td>Analyst</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name_2">
      <td><a href="static\text_files\bill.txt">Bill</a></td>
      <td>54</td>
      <td>Car Salesman</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name_3">
      <td><a id="item_3" href="static\text_files\Rodrigo.txt">Rodrigo</a></td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td id="job_3" onclick="history_buff(this.id)">Merchant</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="block" id="two">
  <h2>History</h2>
  <ul id="user_history">
    <li>Nothing</li>
    <li>Something</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try check this snippet :

```js
function history_buff(value){
  $("#user_history").append('<li><a href="/user/messages"><span class="tab">'+value+'</span></a></li>');

}

function welcome(){
    alert("Welcome home!");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block" id="one">
        <table id="name_table">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Job</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="name_1">
                <td><span onclick="history_buff('Alex');">Alex</span></td>
                <td onclick="welcome();">12</td>
                <td>Analyst</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="name_2"> 
                <td><span onclick="history_buff('Bill');">Bill</span></td>
                <td>54</td>
                <td>Car Salesman</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="name_3">
                <td><a id="item_3" href="static\text_files\Rodrigo.txt">Rodrigo</a></td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td id="job_3" onclick="history_buff(this.id)">Merchant</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="block" id="two">
        <h2>History</h2>
        <ul id="user_history">
            <li>Nothing</li>
            <li>Something</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

You should go through understanding and basic tutorials on Javascript and jQuery. You should achieve your desired outcome easily.

- https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
function history_buff(obj){
    var elList = document.getElementById("user_history");
    var element = document.getElementById(obj)
    var text = element.innerText || element.textContent;
    var user_item = element.innerHTML = text;

    alert("Trying to add: "  + user_item)


    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = user_item;

    elList.appendChild(li);
}
```

Notice from your code:

- str() is not a js function
- li.innerHtml should equal to user_item instead of user_item.value - which is undefined. Then append li to the ul list